# How to use AzerothCore with MySQL 5.7

Tags: azerothcore

After I upgraded my MySQL version from 5.6 to 5.7, the [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) installer fails with errors like:

> ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 234: Invalid default value for 'last_login'
>
> ERROR 1292 (22007) at line 266: Incorrect datetime value: '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for column 'last_login' at row 1

and:

> Can't find any matching row in the user table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: this answer is a bit outdated, some of the issues with MySQL 5.7 have been resolved in the latest version

---

As stated in the [requirements page of the AC wiki](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/wiki/Requirements#mysql-57):

> AzerothCore does not officially support MySQL version >= 5.7, but there is a way to get it up and running.
>
> You have to remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_DATE` flags from MySQL's sql_mode variable in the MySQL config file so that all queries updates and core statements can be applied correctly.

I've found it useful to set my SQL mode to the empty string (which in my case solved all the issues with MySQL 5.7):

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode = ''`

you can run that sql statement via terminal using:

`mysql -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';"`

or alternatively you can manually set the SQL mode before running any SQL statements:

`SET sql_mode = '';`

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you better do it like this (to avoid removing default modes):

```
-- Select the sql modes
SELECT @@sql_mode;

-- Remove the 2 modes NO_ZERO_IN_DATE and NO_ZERO_DATE and run this query
SET sql_mode = 'mode_1,mode_2,mode_3,mode_4,mode_5';
```

Also this can be put directly in mysql configuration.

After `[mysqld]`:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode = mode_1,mode_2,mode_3,mode_4,mode_5
```

Note: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` can be kept

EDIT: As of march 2019, it's probably not needed at all, we have fixed this but it might occur again in the future